# How can you open a fancybox from a conditional statement and add a class?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a drag-and-drop interaction with 4 drag objects and I want to open a feedback box using fancybox after the user places all the drag elements onto the correct targets -- All incorrect answers snap the drag object back to it's original position. I was able to figure out how to open the fancybox for another interaction that registers a click event on a submit button, but this one needs to launch from an "if" statement. After searching for a solution I found out how to open the fancybox and load the html page containing the feedback message, but I cannot figure out how to add the custom class that formats the content.

Here is how I successfully launched the other fancybox popups:

```
<div class="image right">
    <a class="have-popup fancybox.ajax" href="ajax/shire_lifecycle_05b.html"><img src="css/images/image5.jpg" alt="" /></a>>
```

I need to add the class from the above into the code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var correctSr18 = 0;


 $('.steps-drag-drop .dragable .drag-item').draggable({ 
    snap: ".placeholder",
    revert: "invalid", 
    snapMode: "inner"


});

$(".steps-drag-drop .placeholder1").droppable({
  accept : ".step2",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
    correctSr18++;




    //alert(correctSr18);
    if ( correctSr18 == 4 ) {
    //alert("correct");

    $( this ).addClass( "have-popup fancybox.ajax" );
    $.fancybox.open([
    {
        type: 'iframe',
        href : 'ajax/message-popup-scr18.html'                

    }
], {
    padding : 0

})

}
  }
});

$(".steps-drag-drop .placeholder2").droppable({
  accept : ".step3",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
    correctSr18++;

    //alert(correctSr18);

    if ( correctSr18 == 4 ) {
    //alert("correct");

    $.fancybox.open([
    {
        type: 'iframe',
        href : 'ajax/message-popup-scr18.html'                

    }
], {
    padding : 0
});

}
  }
});

$(".steps-drag-drop .placeholder3").droppable({
  accept : ".step1",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
    correctSr18++;
    //alert(correctSr18);
    if ( correctSr18 == 4 ) {
    //alert("correct");

    $.fancybox.open([
    {
        type: 'iframe',
        href : 'ajax/message-popup-scr18.html'
    }
], {
    padding : 0
});

}
  }
});

$(".steps-drag-drop .placeholder4").droppable({
  accept : ".step4",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
    correctSr18++;
    //alert(correctSr18);
    if ( correctSr18 == 4 ) {
    //alert("correct");

    $.fancybox.open([
    {
        type: 'iframe',
        href : 'ajax/message-popup-scr18.html'
    }
], {
    padding : 0
});

}
  }
});
```

Comment: hey, good to see your code, but can you place this in jsfiddle and share

Comment: So is ajax or is iframe?